# How to print only a portion of JSON object's data?

Tags: python, json

I call an API and I get data like:

```
{"states": [{"state_id": 1, "state_name": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"},
            {"state_id": 2, "state_name": "Andhra Pradesh"},
            {"state_id": 3, "state_name": "Arunachal Pradesh"},
            {"state_id": 4, "state_name": "Assam"}], "ttl": 24}
```

I want only state name, so I do like this:

```
certificate = requests.get("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
datafrom = certificate.json()
print(datafrom["state_name"])
```

but it will show an error

```
KeyError: 'state_name
```

How to print the state name only in python?

Comment: the first key in the json output is `states`. which is a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data you are getting has the following format: `stringKey: listValue`, and inside the list, you have each dictionaries, so you need to access the key of the dictionaries inside the value list.

```py
>>> [d['state_name'] for d in datafrom['states']]
['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'Andhra Pradesh', 'Arunachal Pradesh', 'Assam']
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access the top-level of your json, which is `states`:

```
datafrom["states"]
```

There you can check the number of states:

```
len(datafrom["states"])
```

which is `4` in your example. Then you could index which state you want and fetch the `state_name` as needed. Example:

```
datafrom["states"][0]["state_name"]
```

which would yield `'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'`.